# How do I connect columns in two Ruby on Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I'm re-writing http://bngb.org as a Rails project (my first). I've gone through Michael Hartl's tutorial. I've created `Group` and `User` models. A group `belongs_to` a user and a user `has_one` group, which is destroyed with the user.

The contact email address for each group should be that of the user who owns the group, and should change when it changes. I see that I can retrieve the address with `group.user.email` in my views, but it looks like this makes a database call each time instead of using cached data. What's the correct way to have a `group.email` column which is linked to `user.email`? Can I do it with what I have, or do I need a third table linked by `has_one through:`?

Thanks very much for your help!
Jeff Covey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [delegates](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :email, to: :user, allow_nil: true
end
```

It'll only make call to user table the first time you use `group.email` and will be cached for the subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks, @Anurag! I’m still seeing several `User Load` lines with this, and no `CACHE User Load`. Will this only cache with the `eager_load` Jon suggests above?

Comment: @JeffCovey Caching is disabled by default in dev environment, if you're using Rails 5, you can do `rake dev:cache` to enable it.

Comment: Yes, I read that in the link Jon gave and I turned it on, but it didn’t change anything. I still get cached Group loads followed by a bunch of direct User loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord's [`after_find` callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) to add that to an attribute. Here's an example:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessor :email

  after_find :attach_email

  private

  def attach_email
    self.email = user.email
  end
end
```

It will make the initial database call to `user` when the object is retrieved from the database, and then save it as an attribute so all subsequent calls do not need to hit the DB.

Comment: Thanks, Orlando! This seems to be causing a problem with code I have in `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` (as best I can tell). I have this there:

    class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
        def home
            @groups = Group.all
            @categories = @groups.select("DISTINCT(CATEGORY)")
        end
    end

When I call `@categories` in my view, `self.email = user.email` raises the error `missing attribute: user_id`. Any ideas?

Jeff

Comment: And... I don't know why my comment won't format nicely. It should be: https://pastebin.com/GsvxSsGT

Thanks again,
Jeff

Comment: The `missing attribute: user_id` error is occurring because with `@groups.select("DISTINCT(CATEGORY)")` you're not selecting the `user_id` field which is needed for ActiveRecord to associate the group with the user. Try `@groups.select("DISTINCT(CATEGORY), user_id")` instead.

Comment: That did it, everything’s caching now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing that when I update `user.email`, `group.email` remains the same. Is there something else I need to do to make it update?

Comment: `group.email` is independent of `user.email` since it's just an attribute and the `after_find` callback is simply assigning the value of `user.email` to it after an ActiveRecord `SELECT` query. When you change the value of `user.email`, there's nothing telling your `group` object about the change. You can solve that with an `after_update` callback on `User` that will update any associate `Group` objects. For example, in `User`: https://pastebin.com/vRuK0UFX

Answer (score 0):

Anurag Aryan's answer suggesting `delegate` is a good start! Given that Rails will cache results for your database queries, it might be good enough for you. Take a look at these docs to [see what Rails does to avoid querying the DB](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching). Have a close look at your server logs too and look for the word `CACHE` at the beginning of your queries.

Here is a sample (from one of my apps) of what to look for:

```
Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/views/guests/reservations/_reservation.html.erb:5
CACHE Unit Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/views/guests/reservations/_reservation.html.erb:5
```

Notice the word CACHE on the third line? That's Rails reporting that the query didn't hit the DB. **If you want to avoid this additional query entirely** use [`eager_load`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load) when getting the groups. I think in your case, this will look like:

```
@groups = Group.eager_load(:user).all
```

In your logs you should see that Rails will construct a query that joins your Groups and Users without a subsequent query.